# unable to test bool output from c function

Tags: zig

I`m trying to check the result of a call to[GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolescreenbufferinfo) that returns a bool

```
const c = @cImport({
    @cInclude("Windows.h");
});

const TermSz = struct { height: usize, width: usize };
var term_sz: TermSz = .{ .height = 0, .width = 0 };
//get terminal size given a tk  ty
pub fn getTermSz() !TermSz {
    var csbi: c.CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO = undefined;

    const stdoutHandle = c.GetStdHandle(c.STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if (stdoutHandle == c.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        return error.FailedToGetStdoutHandle;
    }
    if (c.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(stdoutHandle, &csbi)) {
        return TermSz{
            .width = @as(usize, csbi.dwSize.X),
            .height = @as(usize, csbi.dwSize.Y),
        };
    } else {
        return error.FailedToGetConsoleScreenBufferInfo;
    }
}
```

resulted in

```
main.zig:57:37: error: expected type 'bool', found 'c_int'
    if (c.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(stdoutHandle, &csbi))
```

I tried different ways of casting to int, but none of them were able to run, here are all of the combinations + compiler output. Running zig 0.11.0 on windows 10.

```
main.zig:59:59: error: expected type 'usize', found 'c_short'
    if (c.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(stdoutHandle, &csbi) != 0) {
```

this returns the same error for all int types (u8, u16, u32, i8, i16, i32)

```
 var result: usize = @intCast(c.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(stdoutHandle, &csbi));
    if (result != 0) {


main.zig:59:16: error: expected type 'usize', found 'c_short'
    if (result != 0) {
        ~~~~~~~^~~~
main.zig:59:16: note: unsigned 64-bit int cannot represent all possible signed 16-bit values
```

this returns the same error as version above

```
var zero: i16 = @intCast(0);
var result: i16 = @intCast(c.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(stdoutHandle, &csbi));
if (result != zero) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one problem in your code.

First, as you already realized, `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo` does not return `bool`. Comparing the result to 0 is enough.

Second, [`@as`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#as) does not cast types, it does [type coercion](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#Type-Coercion). You need to use [`@intCast`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#intCast) for `width` and `height`:

```
TermSz{
    .width = @intCast(csbi.dwSize.X),
    .height = @intCast(csbi.dwSize.Y),
}
```

Comment: thank you for the note on @as, was not aware of that. trying `if (c.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(stdoutHandle, &csbi) != 0) {` also fails with `main.zig:59:59: error: expected type 'usize', found 'c_short''`

Comment: What is one the line 59?

Comment: its `if (c.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(stdoutHandle, &csbi) != 0) {`

Comment: I don't see how an error about `usize` and `c_short` can be on that line. Are you sure that you're not missing something else?

Comment: the compiler is pointing precisely at this line

Comment: In your question, the compiler first complains about missing `!= 0` and points to line 57. Then you fix it and the compiler starts pointing to line 59, which must be the line with `.width = ...`. At this point, I have no idea what to tell you.